# Can a tag be created for motorola moto 360?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

I've made two questions related to the moto 360 but I do not have enough rep to create a tag. So if anyone could modify the question to add the tag would be great.

- [Question 1](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89383/is-there-a-way-to-find-the-battery-usage-of-apps-on-moto-360)
- [Question 2](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89337/google-play-services-stopping-on-moto-360)

Comment: It looks like [Shog9](http://android.stackexchange.com/users/3812/shog9) took care of this, so you should be set now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Status completed!

[Shog9♦](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/3812/shog9) has created the [motorola-moto-360](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motorola-moto-360) tag and set it to existing questions (2, which both are your questions).